# spring boot how to unregister guava eventbus listener?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, guava, event-bus

there's a spring boot application. and I create an event like `UserCreateEvent` and have a listener `UserCreateListener`

event:

```
public class UserCreateEvent {
   private Long userId;
}
```

listener:

```
@Component
public class UserCreateListener {
    @Autowired
    private Eventbus eventbus;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.eventbus.register(this)
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onUserCreate(UserCreateEvent event) {
        Long userId = event.getUserId(）;
        // todo something necessary
    }

}


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

now, I want to unregister the `UserCreateListener` after spring boot application startup. how can I make `Eventbus` unregister this event and listener??

Comment: Typo: `@Comonent` => `@Component`, could you update your code please

Comment: @FrançoisMaturel   ok, thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to unregister a component that you have just created? if you don't need it, simply remove the annotation @Component or use the annotation org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter to exclude UserCreateListener from the spring boot context

Comment: @db80  sorry, not explain that clean, this is an example, and  the listener is in an another jar in my dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce an `unregister()` method in the `UserCreateListener`

```
@Component
public class UserCreateListener {
    @Autowired
    private Eventbus eventbus;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.eventbus.register(this)
    }

    public void unregister() {
        this.eventbus.unregister(this)
    }
}
```

Then if you want to unregister get autowired UserCreateListener (or retrieve the bean from application context) and call `listenerInstance.unregister()`

UPDATE

Create your own component and call unregister there. Guess the listener and eventbus are singletons.

```
@Component
public class MyUnregisterService {
    @Autowired
    private Eventbus eventbus;
    @Autowired
    private UserCreateListener listener;

     public void unregister() {
            eventbus.unregister(listener)
     }
}
```

Comment: the listener is in a third party library, I can not change anything. I want to unregister it in my application context.